# How to get monitor width using xrandr --query?

Tags: scripting, xrandr, monitors

I have a shell script, that loops through xrandr to find connected monitors, which get assigned inside of a variable. Inside that loop, I want to have another loop that determines the width of said connected monitors.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can just post process the results of the xrandr using any of your favorite tools like grep, awk, etc.

```
$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.04*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SVIDEO-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

You can get the "connected" screens like :

```
$ xrandr --query |grep -w 'connected'
LVDS-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
#With grep , the use -w means grep for a word.
```

Or with awk:

```
$ xrandr --query |awk '/\<connected\>/{print}'
LVDS-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
```

With awk you can also print various fields from the above output (awk default fields delimiter is white space):

```
$ xrandr --query |awk '/\<connected\>/{print $1}'
LVDS-1
$ xrandr --query |awk '/\<connected\>/{print $3}'
1366x768+0+0
```

Or you can even ask awk to use a customized fields delimiter like space, x and +:

```
$ xrandr --query |awk -F '[ x+]' '/\<connected\>/{print $1,$3,$4}'
LVDS-1 1366 768
```

Then the most easy way to process all your connected screens is to use an array :

```
$ IFS=$'\n' screens=( $(xrandr --query |awk -F '[ x+]' '/\<connected\>/{print $1,$3,$4}') )
$ for screen in "${screens[@]}";do
> echo "$screen" # or do whatever action you want to do with each screen
> done
LVDS-1 1366 768
```